# Doing calculation using array data selected in a combobox

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to write a loan program so that when the user chooses an option from the combobox it displays the data for that selection in a listbox (loan amount, current loan amount, etc.). Then if the user clicks a button it subtracts a payment from the current loan amount. The problem I'm having is making it so that it is processing the data for the loan selected in the combobox and the subtracting and displaying the new loan amount in the list box. Here is the code I have written:

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string[,] loans = new string[4, 6];
    int recordCount = 0;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentLine;
        string[] fields = new string[6];
        int row = 0;
        StreamReader loanReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\loans.txt");

        while (loanReader.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            currentLine = loanReader.ReadLine();
            fields = currentLine.Split(',');

            loans[row, 0] = fields[0];
            loans[row, 1] = fields[1];
            loans[row, 2] = fields[2];
            loans[row, 3] = fields[3];
            loans[row, 4] = fields[4];
            loans[row, 5] = fields[5];

            row = row + 1;
        }
        recordCount = row;
        loanReader.Close();
        int nbrRows = 4;
        txtPrincipal.Text = "0";

        for (int i = 0; i < nbrRows; i++)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(loans[i, 0]);
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        lstDisplay.Items.Clear();
        string fmtStr = "{0,-15}{1,8}{2,30}";
        string fmtStr2 = "{0,-15}{1,8:C}{2,40:C}";
        lstDisplay.Items.Add(string.Format(fmtStr, "Loan #", "Original Balance", "Current Balance"));
        lstDisplay.Items.Add(string.Format(fmtStr2, loans[row, 0], loans[row, 1], loans[row,2]));

    }

    private void btnRP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = 0, currentLoan, interest, interestPmt, monthlyPmt, principalPmt, newBalance;
        string selection = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();

        for (row = 0; row < recordCount; row++)
        {
            if (loans[row, 0] == selection)
            {
                currentLoan = int.Parse(loans[row, 2]);
                interest = int.Parse(loans[row, 3]);
                monthlyPmt = int.Parse(loans[row, 5]);

                interestPmt = currentLoan * interest / 1200;
                principalPmt = monthlyPmt - interestPmt;
                newBalance = currentLoan - principalPmt;
                currentLoan = newBalance;

                lstDisplay.Items.Clear();
                string fmtStr = "{0,-15}{1,8}{2,30}";
                string fmtStr2 = "{0,-15}{1,8:C}{2,40:C}";
                lstDisplay.Items.Add(string.Format(fmtStr, "Loan #", "Original Balance", "Current Balance"));
                lstDisplay.Items.Add(string.Format(fmtStr2, loans[row, 0], loans[row, 1], currentLoan));
            }
        }

    }
```

The code displays the combobox info correctly at first before the user clicks the button to update the current loan amount, but once the button is clicked it doesn't change the loan amount in the listbox. How can I fix this?

Apologies if the code is a mess, I'm just starting to learn how to write code. Also, if it helps here is the data in the array:

```
1001,55000,46326.26,7,30,352.61
1010,30000,11757.26,5,15,228.61
1003,1000,406.35,5,1,82.49
1005,5000,2042.72,3,2,207.09
```

The format for the data is the format is Loan number, original balance, current balance, interest rate, term, monthly payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
string selection = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

With:

```
if (loans[row, 0] == selection)
```

The SelectedIndex() property will return the **Index** of the selection, which will be 0 (zero) through Count() - 1; returning -1 if no selection is currently made...so your "selection" variable will **never** match the loan value (ID?).

You'd need to use `SelectedItem()` instead:

```
string selection = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: Awesome! That helped to get past that issue. Now the problem is I'm getting "FormatException was unhandled" at currentLoan = int.Parse(loans[row, 2]);

Answer (score 0):

Since you're starting out coding, first you should make a class for Loan with your different properties on (loan number, amount, interest, whatever else).

Then add a member to your form that is a list of loan objects

```
public List<Loan> MyLoans {get; set;}
```

On form_load read from your text building up this list and set it to the MyLoans property.

Make a function that takes in the list and binds it to the combobox.

On the combobox have the loan number be the datavalue field while the loan amount is the displayvalue field

Then on the button click event, don't bother with the selected index or whatever.  Just get the selected item which should give you access to loan number.

Do a linq query against MyLoans and change whatever property you want to on Loan

```
MyLoans.Where(t=>t.LoanNumber == selecteditem).Single().LoanAmount -= payment; //or something like that
```

Now your loans are updated so you can call the function again that binds the combobox with MyLoans.